# can't print "FlimFlam" from Loops

Tags: java

Write a program to perform the following task.
• Get a single integer argument n from the command line.
• Print out the integers from 1 to n, one per line, except that for multiples of 3, print “Flim” instead of the number, and for multiples of 5, print “Flam” instead of the number. For multiples of both 3 and
5, print “FlimFlam”.

For example, running java Example 6
should produce the output
1
2
Flim
4
Flam
Flim

```
class Example {
    public static void main (String argv[]) {
        if (argv.length != 1)
        usage();
        int n = 0;
        try {
        n = Integer.parseInt(argv[0]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        usage();
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            if (i % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Flim");
            } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Flam");
            } else if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0){
                System.out.println("FlimFlam");
            } else {
                System.out.println(i);
        }
  }

  private static void usage() {
    System.err.println("usage: java Example count string");
    System.exit(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: Ok, the if-else statements are evaluated in the order they are defined. You need to check `i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0` first followed by rest of the checks

Comment: Use i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0 as first if condition.

Comment: `if (i % 3 == 0)` then the `else if` will not be entered into

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the conditions. As either `i % 3` or `i % 5` satisfies first it never reaches to `i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0` condition. Hence, you must be first checking for `i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0` and then for rest two conditions.

Below is modified condition:

```
            if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0){
                System.out.println("FlimFlam");
            } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Flim");
            } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Flam");
            }  else {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
```

**Edit:** - if-else-if blocks are like if any of the first occurring condition matches, don't check for rest of the conditions in the if-else-if block.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code:

```
public class Example {

public static void main(String argv[]) {
    if (argv.length != 1)
        usage();
        int n = 0;
        try {
        n = Integer.parseInt(argv[0]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        usage();
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            if (i % 3 == 0) {
                if(i % 5 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("FlimFlam");
                }
                 System.out.println("Flim");
            } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Flam");
            } else {
                System.out.println(i);
        }
}

private static void usage() {
    System.err.println("usage: java Example count string");
    System.exit(1);
  }
```

}