# How to use logical operator in Java

Tags: java

How does java evaluate the following code with the logical operator in java?

```
public class ApaBoleh{
  public static void main(String[]args){
      for(int i=1;i<=100;i++){
          if(i%3==0){
              System.out.print("Apa,");
          }else if (i%5==0){
              System.out.print("Boleh,");
          }else if ((i%3==0)&&(i%5==0)){
              System.out.print("ApaBoleh,");
          }
         System.out.print(i+",");
      }
  }
}
```

when I run this code, the following line doesn't run 
`}else if ((i%3==0)&&(i%5==0)){`.

Comment: 1) `}else if ((i%3==0)&&(i%5==0)){` is not a function. 2) Your code runs without any error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can't print "FlimFlam" from Loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58213096/cant-print-flimflam-from-loops)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before run

`else if ((i%3==0)&&(i%5==0)){ System.out.print("ApaBoleh,");}`

it runs

```
if(i%3==0){
    System.out.print("Apa,");
}else if (i%5==0){
    System.out.print("Boleh,");
```

so you have to put

```
else if ((i%3==0)&&(i%5==0)){ System.out.print("ApaBoleh,");}
```

before above two

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using `else` to exclude anything prior to that condition that resolves to true. Try checking the most exclusive case first:

```
if (( i%3 == 0 ) && ( i%5 == 0 )){
    System.out.print("ApaBoleh,");
}else if ( i%3 == 0){
    System.out.print("Apa,");
}else if ( i%5 == 0){
    System.out.print("Boleh,");
}

System.out.print(i+",");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an `else` where **both** preceding `if`(s) are `true`; only the first is entered. I would save the tests to local variables because repeating all of those modulus operations is not very clean. Like,

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    boolean mod3 = i % 3 == 0, mod5 = i % 5 == 0;
    if (mod3 && mod5) {
        System.out.print("ApaBoleh,");
    } else if (mod3) {
        System.out.print("Apa,");
    } else if (mod5) {
        System.out.print("Boleh,");
    }
    System.out.print(i + ",");
}
```

See also [The FizzBuzz challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/56829/33166).

Answer (score 1):

Of course it'll not run, the moment one of your previous two if conditions evaluate to `true`, you'll never get to that if block.

For example, if `i = 3` then your first condition `if(i%3==0)` will evaluate to `true` and your print out `Apa`, since the rest of the conditions are `else if` the java code will stop processing and go to the next loop iteration. Similarly, if `i = 5` then first condition will evaluate to `false` and the second condition `if(i%5==0)` will evaluate to `true` and will not continue to the next `else if`

Hence if either of your previous conditions evaluate to `true` you'll not get to your third condition.

Apart from this, if you had to remove the preceding two `if` statemets and only evaluate that condition as follows:

```
public class ApaBoleh{
  public static void main(String[]args){
    for(int i=1;i<=100;i++){
      if ((i%3==0)&&(i%5==0)){
        System.out.print("ApaBoleh,");
      }
     System.out.print(i+",");
    }
  }
}
```

Then if `i = 3` it'll evaluate to `false` because it'll evaluate `i%3==0` as `true` and then go on to evaluate `i%5==0` as `false` (`true` and `false` = `false`).

Then if `i = 15` it'll evaluate to `true` because it'll evaluate `i%3==0` as `true` and then go on to evaluate `i%5==0` as `true` (`true` and `true` = `false`).

Answer (score 0):

The conditions inside your `}else if ((i%3==0)&&(i%5==0)){` evaluates as true whenever i%3 is equal to 0 or i%5 is equal to 0 so, if you really want `}else if ((i%3==0)&&(i%5==0)){` to run you could either use `}if ((i%3==0)&&(i%5==0)){` instead of it or you should at least place it above `}else if (i%5==0){` or you could use it like this like the others told before me:

```
public class ApaBoleh{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        for(int i=1;i<=100;i++){
            if ((i%3==0)&&(i%5==0)){
                System.out.print("ApaBoleh,");
            }else if (i%5==0){
                System.out.print("Boleh,");
            }else if(i%3==0){
                System.out.print("Apa,");
            }
            System.out.print(i+",");
       }
    }
}
```